# BrowserMob Proxy is not opening 2nd page in chrome (Internet connection goes off after landing to 2nd page)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver, har, browsermob-proxy

I'm running Windows 10 virtual machine on ubuntu, and on VM I have following versions :-

`Eclipse neon, Selenium Webdriver 3.0.1, Mozilla Firefox 51.0.1, Google Chrome 55, geckoDriver v0.11.1, Chromedriver v2.27, BrowserMob Proxy jar 2.1.4, jackson-all-1.7.3.jar, harlib-1.1.2.jar`

I wanted to read browser traffics in selenium and for that i opted for `BrowserMob proxy`. I have 2 page of communication on the browser  like `Authenticates url, Lands on the 1st page clicks a dropdown menu (link) and lands on the 2nd page`

When the second page opens the page does not load but the calls are going behind. What i noticed is in the VM when the second page loads internet connectivity goes off at that page only (internet sign stops blinking).

When i Reboot both `the VM & the host machine` and then execute the code. It loads the page at first attempt after fresh reboot of the system then again, if i execute the same code same problem persists.

But the traffic data is getting logged in the file. The same code if i try to execute in `geckodriver(Firefox)` then the page is getting loaded but traffic is not getting captured.`capturing only specific urls from the log data`

I have stuck in both the ways.  Please find below the code :-

class 1 :-

```
public class BrowserMobExample{         

public static String sFileName = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\CaptureNetworkTraffic\\BrowserMob.har";

WebDriver driver = null;
BrowserMobProxy proxy = null;

@BeforeTest
public void setUp() throws Exception {

   // start the proxy
    proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    proxy.start(0);

    //get the Selenium proxy object - org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
    Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);

    // configure it as a desired capability
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);

    //set chromedriver system property
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "path to chromedriver");      
    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    /*System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path to geckodriver");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);*/

    // enable more detailed HAR capture, if desired (see CaptureType for the complete list)
    proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_HEADERS, CaptureType.RESPONSE_HEADERS);


    proxy.newHar("label_for_har");      


    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://username:pswd@url.com");        
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Robot rb = new Robot();
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);     

    //do something on page
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement citySelect = driver.findElement(By.xpath("dropdown_xpath"));
    Select dropdown= new Select(select_a_dropdown_menuitem);            
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Text_displayed");
    //driver.navigate().refresh();

}

@Test
public void testCaseOne() throws AWTException {
    /*driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://username:pswd@url.com");        
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Robot rb = new Robot();
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);     

    //do something on page
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebElement citySelect = driver.findElement(By.xpath("dropdown_xpath"));
    Select dropdown= new Select(select_a_dropdown_menuitem);            
    dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Text_displayed");
    //driver.navigate().refresh();*/

}

@AfterTest
public void tearDown() {

    // get the HAR data
    Har har = proxy.getHar();

    // Write HAR Data in a File
    File harFile = new File(sFileName);
    try {
        har.writeTo(harFile);
        ReadHAR reading = new ReadHAR();
        reading.main(null);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
         System.out.println (ex.toString());
         System.out.println("Could not find file " + sFileName);
    }   

    /*if (driver != null) {
        proxy.stop();
        //driver.quit();
    }*/
}
 }
```

class 2 :-

```
public class ReadHAR {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String filename = new String();
filename = BrowserMobExample.sFileName;
 // System.out.println("This is the file location " + filename);

File f = new File(filename);
HarFileReader r = new HarFileReader();
HarFileWriter w = new HarFileWriter();

try
{
  System.out.println("Reading " + filename);
  HarLog log = r.readHarFile(f);

  // Access all elements as objects
  HarBrowser browser = log.getBrowser();
  HarEntries entries = log.getEntries();

  // Used for loops
  List<HarPage> pages = log.getPages().getPages();
  List<HarEntry> hentry = entries.getEntries();
  String string1 = "p_still_media";
  String string2 = "m_still_media";
  String string3 = "T-Map";


   /* for (HarPage page : pages)
  {
    System.out.println("page start time: "
        + ISO8601DateFormatter.format(page.getStartedDateTime()));
    System.out.println("page id: " + page.getId());
    System.out.println("page title: " + page.getTitle());

    }*/

  File varTmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\CaptureNetworkTraffic\\results.txt");
  boolean exists = varTmpDir.exists();
  System.out.println("  result.txt : " +exists);
  System.out.println(" file path:"+ varTmpDir);
  if(exists){
      varTmpDir.delete();
  }
  File result = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\CaptureNetworkTraffic\\results.txt");

 // result.createNewFile();
  result.setWritable(true);
  //FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(result, false);
 // PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fw);



  //Output "response" code of entries.
  for (HarEntry entry : hentry)
  {
     // System.out.println("IP is : " + entry.getServerIPAddress());

      if(entry.getRequest().getUrl().contains(string2)/* & entry.getResponse().getStatus() !=200*/){
      System.out.println("    Url is : " + entry.getRequest().getUrl() + "    response code: " + entry.getResponse().getStatus()); //Output url of request
     // Files.newBufferedWriter(result, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    //  out.write("    Url is : " + entry.getRequest().getUrl() + "    response code: " + entry.getResponse().getStatus());
     // BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
     System.out.println("IP is :- "+entry.getServerIPAddress());
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(result, true);
      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);

      out.write("    Url is : " + entry.getRequest().getUrl() + "    response code: " + entry.getResponse().getStatus());
      out.newLine();
      out.close();
      fw.close();

      }
      else if(entry.getRequest().getUrl().contains(string3) /*& entry.getResponse().getStatus() !=200*/){
         // System.out.println("request code: " + entry.getRequest().getMethod()); //Output request type
          System.out.println("    Url is: " + entry.getRequest().getUrl() + "    response code: " + entry.getResponse().getStatus()); //Output url of request
         // out.write("    Url is : " + entry.getRequest().getUrl() + "    response code: " + entry.getResponse().getStatus());
          FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(result, true);
          BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);

          out.write("    Url is : " + entry.getRequest().getUrl() + "    response code: " + entry.getResponse().getStatus());
          out.newLine();
          out.close();
          fw.close();

      }
      else if(entry.getRequest().getUrl().contains(string1) /*& entry.getResponse().getStatus() !=200*/){
         // System.out.println("request code: " + entry.getRequest().getMethod()); //Output request type
           System.out.println("    Url is: " + entry.getRequest().getUrl() + "    response code: " + entry.getResponse().getStatus()); //Output url of request
           //out.write("    Url is : " + entry.getRequest().getUrl() + "    response code: " + entry.getResponse().getStatus());
         //  out.close();
           //System.out.println("    response code: " + entry.getResponse().getStatus()); // Output the
           FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(result, true);
           BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);

           out.write("    Url is : " + entry.getRequest().getUrl() + "    response code: " + entry.getResponse().getStatus());
           out.newLine();
           out.close();
           fw.close();

      }

  }

  /*
  // Once you are done manipulating the objects, write back to a file
  System.out.println("Writing " + "fileName" + ".test");
  File f2 = new File("fileName" + ".test");
  w.writeHarFile(log, f2);
  */
}
catch (JsonParseException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
  //fail("Parsing error during test");
}
catch (IOException e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
  //fail("IO exception during test");
}
}

}
```

With `ChromeDriver` logs are getting generated but the page is not loading. With firefox page is loading but logs are not captured (I think for geckodriver browsermob proxy is not compatible or this feature isn't available yet)

Am i missing anything or what is the issue ? Stuck on this since more than a week. Tried the above on `ubuntu` to but facing the same issue.

Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Anuragh27crony for the edit.